# Magento2 When uncheck checkbox then order total is not updated?

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.4.5

i have added one custom checkbox. when i uncheck checkbox and then ajax to controller but order total is not update.

below code
phtml code :

```
var customurl = "<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl().'points/index/redeem';//phpcs:ignore?>";
                $.ajax({
                    url: customurl,
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {},
                    showLoader: true,
                    complete: function(response) {
                        console.log('sucess');
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                        console.log('Error happens. Try again.');
                    }
                });
```

controller code:

```
 public function execute()
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $checkoutSession=$objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
        $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
        $resultRedirectFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory');

        $shipping_amount=$cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingAmount();


        $quote = $checkoutSession->getQuote();
        $grand_total = $quote->getGrandTotal();
        $new_grand_total = $grand_total + $shipping_amount;
        $quote->setBaseGrandTotal($new_grand_total);
        $quote->save();

        $checkoutSession->getQuote()->collectTotals()->save();
        $resultRedirect = $resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
        echo 'test';

        return $resultRedirect;

    }
```

if you any kind solution.please send me message.
Thank you.

Comment: Where Order Total is not updated?

Comment: in cart page order total is not updated.